# Describing continuity and change (like mou and mada in Japanese)

Tags: grammar, list-of-languages, japanese, adverbs, aspect

In Japanese, *[mada](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%81%BE%E3%81%A0)* まだ refers to a continuing state: 'still (as it was)' or 'not (changed) yet', and *[mou](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%82%E3%81%86)* もう is about change: 'already (changed)' or 'no longer (the same)'. Are there other languages using a similar pair of words?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for example English as you pointed out in the question.

Or Norwegian: "ennå" and "allerede".

Or Dutch: "nog", and "al"

Or Czech: "ještě" and "již"

Or Mandarin:  還 and  已經

So basically it seems like all languages have ways to express these concepts.